# how to Toggle class of particular div by jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have Code like this.

```
<div class="friend cell">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <span class="name">Bob</span>
                            <br />
                            (id: 57)
                            <input type="hidden" class="friend_id" value="57 " />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I want to toggle class after friend.

my script is like this.

```
$("div.friend").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
            });
```

but its not working

Comment: @H H F: Have you put `$(function({ ... your last code ... });` ?

Comment: _"I want to toggle class after friend." _What is _"class after friend"_ ??

Comment: Are you trying to toggle it on the outer or inner div? Also you don't have to use `div.friend` you can just use `.friend` it's slightly faster and a bit cleaner and means your not as tied to the implementation.

Comment: friend cell  and i want like friend highlight cell

Comment: Sorry, I've probably misread the word 'after' in your question. Anyway, what's 'not working'? Some error shown in console? Or just no visible action?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,(passing parameter) it worked for me!

```
$("div.friend").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("highlight",1);
        });
```